# Swagger running with local json file in Docker Image

Tags: json, docker, swagger, swagger-ui

So, I wanted to run the **local Swagger UI** with respect to Local Json. And for that I am following the instructions available [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/installation.md):

Here is the command that is being shared in that documentation:

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.json -v /bar:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Here I understand the **-p** option but this **-e** and **-v** is confusing.

So let's assume I have **kept a JSON file at my desktop in Mac** whose path is :

`/Users/abc/Desktop/lp.json` so with respect to this file the command will gets changed to:

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/Users/abc/Desktop/lp.json -v /bar:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

But what about the **-v** part of the command. What is the value that I need to put with respect to **-v** option, although the basic command i.e :

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Runs and SwaggerUI is available at **http:localhost:8081** but with default Json and not with my Json, i.e with `http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json`

So my query is what should I make a change to the command of **docker** that will run the image of the SwaggerUI with my local JSON?

Please help. Thanks in advance.
 &
Happy coding
:)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the docker command `-v` means to mount a volume and `-e` means to add environment variables, so what you want is probbably this:

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/mnt/lp.json -v /Users/abc/Desktop:/mnt swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Comment: not working for me, this is my command
`docker run -p 9000:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/Users/abc/Downloads/swagger/swagger.json -v /Users/abc/Desktop:/Users/faizal/Downloads/swagger swaggerapi/swagger-ui`

Comment: You're doing it wrong, this is what you need (if your file is located at /Users/faizal/Downloads/swagger/swagger.json ): `docker run -p 9000:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/mnt/swagger.json -v /Users/faizal/Downloads/swagger:/mnt swaggerapi/swagger-ui` @FaiZalDong

Comment: hi @psrcek thank you for replying, I already followed your steps but the swagger still use default json `https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json`. is it because of version of swagger?

Comment: @psrcek Thanks for explanation! 
I have a swagger.json on my desktop so running this command worked 
`docker run -p 9000:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/mnt/swagger.json -v ~/Desktop:/mnt swaggerapi/swagger-ui` -  http://localhost:9000/ is loading correct file.

Comment: this is ok for me @David but how can I  get the Json or YAML file or add these line to get that file in docker-compose.yml configuration for swagger-ui

Answer (score 5):

For me following command helped

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/tmp/swagger.json -v `pwd`/docs:/tmp swaggerapi/swagger-ui:v3.21.0
```

'pwd'/docs => Contains my swagger.json file.

swaggerapi/swagger-ui:v3.21.0 => This version is supported SWAGGER_JSON.Its tested.

Answer (score 4):

The way it worked for me on Windows is this:

`docker run -p 80:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/mnt/swagger-v1.json -v C:\Users\jimen\Downloads:/mnt swaggerapi/swagger-ui`

where `C:\Users\jimen\Downloads` is the folder where the local swagger file is located (`swagger-v1.json`).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifying `SWAGGER_JSON` you can do the following to immediatelly get your API spec openend in Swagger UI:

```
docker run --name my-swagger-ui -p 80:8080 -e URL=api/openapi.yaml -v ${PWD}://usr/share/nginx/html/api swaggerapi/swagger-ui:v3.51.1
```

This is also tested with the latest `swagger-ui` image which was published one day ago.

**NOTE:** I ran this command from Windows, thus specifying the environment variable `${PWD}` maybe a bit different in Linux.

---

#### What is happening behind the curtain

What's happening here is, that you mount a volume (`-v ${PWD}://usr/share/nginx/html/api`) in the nginx html folder which contains your swagger spec (in this case `openapi.yaml`). With `-e URL=api/openapi.yaml` the default URL will be overwritten and instead your swagger spec will be used.

Answer (score 1):

I actually wanted `swagger-editor` and not `swaggerapi/swagger-ui`:

```
docker pull swaggerapi/swagger-editor
docker run -p 7999:8080 swaggerapi/swagger-editor
```

Then you get a full `File` menu:

[image: Before I had a pull the]

Answer (score 0):

As of 22-Aug-2022, if you are running on macbook with Apple Silicon, the current docker image in docker hub does not run on Apple Silicon (only supported for amd64 platform and not arm64 platform). A simple workaround for that is to just build the image locally by cloning [swagger editor](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor) and then running the following commands from the clone repository:

```
$ docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 --tag swagger-editor:latest . --load
$ docker run -p 9090:8080 -e SWAGGER_FILE=/tmp/openapi.yaml -v <local_directory_containing_openapi_spec_files>:/tmp swagger-editor:latest
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).